# Clojure DB Connection

Tags: clojure

I am new to Clojure. I have defined a datasource in Weblogic 11. I have the below in my code. I am neither getting any error/exception nor am I able to connect to the database.

```
(def cms-apacdb {:name "APACCMSInterfaceDataSource"})
(defn update-or-insert-apacitem [table-name {cms-content-id :cms_content_id :as cms-item}]
(with-connection cms-apacdb
  (update-or-insert-values
    table-name
    ["cms_content_id = ?" cms-content-id]
    (assoc cms-item :updated (now))))
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You problem description is quite vague, could you please provide details about DB type, version etc.?

Comment: What is the JNDI configuration for the data source? You can exclude username and password. Could it be that you're pointed to a different database than what you think?